# WebStorm and TypeScript intellisense

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I am trying to get intellisense for TypeScript working in WebStorm.

In my test here I am trying to get it for Knockout.

I have added the type definition file and other files necessary, added the reference tag to the top of my .ts file.

Here is a screenshot of my setup:

[image]

When I type 'ko.' I can scroll through the list and find observable but other than that I get no other intellisense.

Is there something wrong with my setup? Am I wrong to expect overloads and such when I open a paren after typing 'ko.observable'?

If I change the line

```
declare var ko : KnockoutState
```

to

```
declare var ko : KnockoutObservable<string>;
```

I get the error

> 'Error:(3, 13) TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the
>   same type.  Variable 'ko' must be of type 'KnockoutStatic', but here
>   has type 'KnockoutObservable'.

(UPDATE) NOTE: I mention the above error only to show that it does seem to be reading the type definition for Knockout. I still do not get any intellisense when I leave it at KnockoutStatic or remove the type out completely.

Answer (score 0):

> When I type 'ko.' I can scroll through the list and find observable but other than that I get no other intellisense.

You need  to use it in code to get intellisense. I can see you tried that with :

```
declare var ko : KnockoutObservable<string>;
```

Which is an *invalid* usage ... and hence you got the error `TS2403`.

## Fix

Use `ko` properly:

```
var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray<any>();  // intellisense on `ko.`
myObservableArray.push('Some value');               // intellisense on `.p`
var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]);
```

Comment: I don't get intellisense with KnockoutStatic or leaving it blank. I know ko is not the correct class.